# Use a system class with a different name?

Tags: c#, naming, renaming

I need a way to track the numbers of rows and columns in a grid.  If I use System.Point, I am always going to be forgetting whether "x" is the number of rows or columns.  So I have the class below.

But I'm wondering if there is a way to use System.Point, with a different naming skin?  In other words, I do **not** want to define a general "NRows" or "NColumns" method on System.Point.  But I do want to be able to return an object that code will see as an "NRowsColumns" object, but in fact compiles to System.Point.  When accessing an "NRowsColumns" object, we use the fields "NRows" and "NColumns" instead of "x" and "y".  But under the hood, it actually compiles to a System.Point.

Ideally, this definition would not be restricted to a single file.

```
public class NRowsColumns
{
  public int NRows {get;set;}
  public int NColumns {get;set;}
  public NRowsColumns(int nRows, int nColumns)
  {
    this.NRows = nRows;
    this.NColumns = nColumns;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't "rename" members like that. You can refer to `System.Point` as `NRowsColumns` if you really want, as

```
using NRowsColumns = System.Point;
```

... but it would still have the same members as `System.Point`.

It would be simpler to just implement `NRowsColumns` by *composing* a `System.Point` though:

```
public class NRowsColumns
{
    private Point point;

    public int NRows
    {
        get { ... } // Code using point
        set { ... } // Code using point
    }

    ...
}
```

Having said that:

- I can't see that a `Point` really has anything to do with a number of rows and columns. Why not just have two integers?
- I would revisit your naming here... the `N` prefix is unconventional. I would probably call it `GridSize` with `Rows` and `Columns` - although even this seems unnecessary as a separate type, in general. (Why does your grid itself not expose its size via `Rows` and `Columns` properties?)

Comment: Good advice on naming. If the OP wants `NumberOfRows`, then use that as the property name; otherwise just use `Rows`. `NRows` is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [conversion operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) to allow your code to use your `NRowsColumns` and `Point` interchangeably.

Note, this is not a perfect solution. Creating objects back and forth has impacts that you should investigate.

Add the `implicit operator` conversions to your existing class:

```
public class NRowsColumns
{
    public int NRows { get; set; }
    public int NColumns { get; set; }
    public NRowsColumns(int nRows, int nColumns)
    {
        this.NRows = nRows;
        this.NColumns = nColumns;
    }

    public static implicit operator NRowsColumns(Point p)
    {
        return new NRowsColumns(p.X, p.Y);
    }

    public static implicit operator Point(NRowsColumns rowsColumns)
    {
        return new Point(rowsColumns.NRows, rowsColumns.NColumns);
    }
}
```

Now you can convert back and forth:

```
Point point1 = new Point(5, 10);
NRowsColumns nRowsColumns = point1;
Point point2 = nRowsColumns;
```

Keep in mind that every "conversion" is a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just inherit from Point?

```
public struct  NRowsColumns: Point
{
   public int NRows {get {return base.x;}}
   public int NColumns {get {return base.y;}}
   public NRowsColumns(int nRows, int nColumns) 
      : base(nRows, nColumns)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Inheritance is a bad idea at the best of times. Encouraging its use in superficial ways like this is just plain bad advice.

Comment: Why do you think it's a bad idea? the entire OOP concept is built on inheritance (among other things).  I agree that it should be used to extend existing objects capabilities, but I don't see anything wrong in using it to improve code readability. Please enlighten me.

Comment: You can find a good explanation of the evils of inheritance and why interfaces and composition make for better code at http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/01/15/inheritance-is-inherently-evil/

Comment: @DavidArno Still you can't say "Ok, i give you 100% that inheritance is evil and never use it". But in this case i agree with you. This is not the best spot to use inheritance and strictly  speaking it is a good practice to use it no more than it is necessary.

Comment: @Fabjan, I can say that, though I accept it's a pace-setting position to adopt. I completely avoid any use of `goto`, `switch` and inheritance and my code is better for it. Others will catch up to this position in time. :)

Comment: @DavidArno Interesting reading material. I'm not so sure I agree with everything written there (currently reading jon skeet`s [inheritance tax](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2006/03/04/inheritancetax/) article, he does have some good points there, but I'm not sure avoiding inheritance at all costs is such a great idea. I believe you should use every tool in your toolbox wisely, and inheritance is no exception.